# Same position for UI elements (buttons, image buttons) on all android devices

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, devise, imagebutton

My application uses buttons and image buttons constructed via XML and drawable folder.
On some devices applications UI elements (buttons and image buttons) losses its position and overlaps on each other and on some devices last button in bottom of screen  disappears.
Same is happening when orientation is changed.

I want all my elements to be on same position on all devices.
How can I make this using XML.
Is there any easy and simple way to do so?
Here is my XML.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/bg"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/main_btn_1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="55dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="71dp"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/main_btn_2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/main_btn_1"
        android:layout_marginRight="56dp"
        android:background="#000000"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/main_btn_1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/main_btn_1"
        android:textColor="#00aeed"
        android:textStyle="normal" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/main_btn_2"
        android:textColor="#ea1d24"
        android:textStyle="normal" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/main_btn_3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="42dp"
        android:background="#000000"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/main_btn_3"
        android:layout_below="@+id/main_btn_3"
        android:textColor="#f7941d"
        android:textStyle="normal" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/main_btn_4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/main_btn_3"
        android:background="#000000"
         />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/main_btn_4"
        android:layout_below="@+id/main_btn_4"
        android:textColor="#f7941d"
        android:textStyle="normal" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/main_btn_5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:background="#000000"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/main_btn_5"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textColor="#0065b3"
        android:textStyle="normal" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Are you using resolution aware graphics?

Comment: Yes I did, used 9 Patch for each image

Answer (score 0):

Because there are many devices with so many different screen sizes, resolutions, etc., probably the main thing you have to avoid is using absolute positions when placing layout elements. The Android SDK has some powerful structures to avoid absolute positioning (i.e. LinearLayout, RelativeLayout), so try working with them and instead of defining positions like "12dp", use the correct combination of layout_width, layout_height (wrap_content or match_parent) and layout_weight, which can help you to place layout elements without specifying absolute positions.

Comment: In facts, he's using a RelativeLayout, with all positions relative to each other (alignTop, toLeftOf, alignParentRight, ... all RELATIVE positioning - not absolute).

Comment: But he's using `wrap_content` in all of them instead of using the `layout_weight` parameter which would help normalizing the layout on most of the devices.

Comment: I tried this approach as well but unable to make it working. Like I want first image button (main_btn_1) to be places 2 or 5 pixel from left I cannot do it with out dp. If there is any way please suggest

Comment: layout_weight can be used only in LinearLayouts. And it only works on 1 dimension at a time (the one you set to 0dp). So, to have a bidimensional redistribution via weights, you have to nest LinearLayouts... what a mess!! If you take you time, you can do the same redistribution via RelativeLayouts, using less layouts.

Comment: The problem in your layout is that you're using `wrap_content` as `layout_width` everywhere. Getting in mind that there are many different widths in different devices, happens that in some of them the "row" simply doesn't fit, and is wrapped into the next line. I would use a `LinearLayout` with `android:orientation="horizontal"` and place there as many ellements you wish to show in one line, and use `layout_weight` to set the relative width they should have.